# SGDClassifier kernel dies when using scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried this very simple example

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

but the Kernel dies immediately

```
Kernel died, restarting
```

Fitting a Random Forest works without problem:

```
from sklearn import ensemble
clf2 = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
clf2.fit(X, Y)
```

I have no idea why this occurs. I am using the current version of anaconda3 with all updates on a ubuntu 16.04 64bit system.

UPDATE: I just found that this happens with all model from the `linear_model` class

UPDATE2: MKL was the problem, as described here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5046

and `conda install nomkl` fixed it.

Comment: I think you should add an answer with your solution, because it really solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKL is the problem, as described here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5046

and `conda install nomkl` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You could update your scikit-learn package.
If you are using Anaconda  update using conda like this:

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

if this doesn' t fix the problem

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```