# When using LinearRegression in python I get the message "Kernel died, restarting"

Tags: python, windows, scikit-learn, spyder

I'm pretty new to python. In the code below, whenever I run the last line, I get the message "Kernel died, restarting" and Kernel just restarts.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import traceback


dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
conda install nomkl
```

The same issue is discussed in another post: [SGDClassifier kernel dies when using scikit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720911/sgdclassifier-kernel-dies-when-using-scikit)

The author of the question provides a link to the original error discussion as well: [Issue #5046 of scikit-learn, build with anaconda/MKL.](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5046)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your scikit-learn package.
If you are using Anaconda update using conda like this:

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

if this doesn' t fix the problem

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734044/kernel-appears-to-have-died-jupyter-notebook-python-matplotlib)

So try:

```
import os 
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK'] = 'True'
```

That solved the issue for me