# Kernel appears to have died - Jupyter notebook python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to learn charting in Python and keep getting this message in Jupyter:

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

My other basic programs are working, so it looks like using Matplotlib is causing this problem. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: Screenshot of message I am getting]

Comment: Have you already taken a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47547114
The suggestion is to reinstall the faulty library

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. I tried that already. I also uninstalled and reinstalled Jupiter and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: what is your OS? How did you install both Jupyter and Python?

Answer (score 20):

if you don't solve the problem after using method above, you can try this:

```
import os    
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK'] = 'True'
```

add two lines of codes in your python code. This mothed is also useful to pycharm.

Comment: why do we need to add this line of code ? is there an permenant solution instead of adding it all the time

Comment: In 2023 with latest conda, this worked for me. The freetype upgrade in other answers didn't work.

Comment: @npkp I found an explanation of that variable here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74217717/what-does-os-environkmp-duplicate-lib-ok-actually-do .  To use it as a permanent solution, since it's an environment variable, you'd follow your OS' instructions for setting an environment variable permanently.

Answer (score 2):

If the `libiomp5md.dll` file is not in the binary exectuables folder of your environment, then this may be the cause of the kernel dying.

1. Download the `libiomp5md.dll` file from a trusted online source. I used https://www.dll-files.com/libiomp5md.dll.html and downloaded the latest version. I do not condone the use of this link, and please do your own research to find a trusted source to download this file.
2. Navigate to -> `./anaconda3/envs/your_env_name/Library/bin` and add the `libiomp5md.dll` file to that folder.
3. `matplotlib` should now work without kernel dying, as it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

I try the solution of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6D33x_eQt2U), based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786885/after-conda-update-python-kernel-crashes-when-matplotlib-is-used), and it worked for me:

- Run Anaconda Prompt as administrator
- `conda install --yes freetype=2.10.4`

Answer (score 1):

I did the following :

```
conda install --yes freetype=2.10.4
```

it works. Great!

Comment: This is exactly what the already existing answer proposes. Please don't add answers that do not add any new information.

Comment: does not seem to be working anymore.